# Function for shaking the phone on the PWA mobile application

Tags: javascript, mobile, progressive-web-apps, accelerometer, shake

I need a JavaScript function that will randomly select a category after shaking the phone.

I've tried using shake.js, Window: deviceorientation event, Window: devicemotion event, Accelerometer, but with each of these options I get "The use of function is deprecated.".

I want the category to be selected when shaken, which will then trigger the appropriate randomization function.

```js
const generateCategoryButtons = () => {
    newGameModal.classList.add("show");

    levelsList.forEach(level => {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = level.name;
        button.classList.add("levels-button");

        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            newGameModal.classList.remove("show");
            getRandomWord();
        });

        levelsContainer.appendChild(button);
    });

    categoriesList.forEach(category => {
        const button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = category.name;
        button.classList.add("categories-button");

        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            getRandomWord();
            newGameModal.classList.remove("show");
        });

        categoriesContainer.appendChild(button);
    });
};
```

[image]

Comment: Show us your shakejs attempt.

Comment: `const Shake = require('./shake.js');

const myShakeEvent = new Shake({
    threshold: 15, 
    timeout: 1000 
});

myShakeEvent.start();

window.addEventListener('shake', shakeEventDidOccur, false);

function shakeEventDidOccur() {
    alert('shake!');
}

window.removeEventListener('shake', shakeEventDidOccur, false);

myShakeEvent.stop();`

in the code above, the function call has already been removed because it destroyed the operation of the application